# Continue loading view after method loads from external URL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method to retrieve data from an external url, load it into an array from JSON format, and populate a UITableView.  It works fine, but there is no indication to the user that something is happening while the data is downloaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self retrieveDataC];

}
```

Here is the code that I tried for viewDidLoad which adds a spinner animation while downloading.  I'm attempting to put `retrieveDataC` on a background thread and when it completes, I would like the view to continue executing as though I didn't implement the multi-threading in the example above.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [self retrieveDataC];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        });
    });

}
```

The loading spinner displays correctly for a brief moment, however after the process is done I'm left with a blank table as though I have not called `[self retrieveDataC]` to begin with.  Any suggestions, advice?  Am I setting up the background process correctly?

Thank you

EDIT:

Here's what ended up working -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [self retrieveDataC];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after you received the data?

Comment: Yes.  But it was at the end of `retrieveDataC`.  I moved it out under `[spinner stopAnimating];` and it worked.  Any idea why it wouldn't work tagged at the bottom of `retrieveDataC`?

Comment: Because you should call reloadData on the main thread(queue). Read more at this article: [Thread-Safe Class Design](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/thread-safe-class-design.html)